# PHP - destruct clarification

Tags: php, oop, destructor, unset

I am just learning OOP with PHP and I am trying to get my head around this:

I am using php version 5.6.10 on my MAMP installation if that makes a difference??

This the code I have:

```
<?php

    class Baddie {
        public $evilness = 10;
    }

    class Boss extends Baddie {
        public $evilness = 50;

        public function changeEvilness($value)
        {
            //$this->$evilness = $value; Had this, which was a typo
            $this->evilness = $value;
        } 

        public function __destruct() {

            echo "You beat the boss!";
        }

    }

    $ganon = new Boss;

?>
```

`//Note the code is from Rob Percivals Udemy course, hence the gaming references.`

So when I call a new instance of the Boss class, it gets destroyed automatically. This prevents me from changing the "evilness" of the boss.

How do I change the code, or maybe a php setting that the destruct() is not called automatically, but only with the `unset()` function so that I can call other methods from with that class?

**Changes**
I have updated the typo error, but the answers provided still apply.

Comment: The destructor is automatically called, when there is no reference anymore to a specific object. Can't change it (btw: `$this->$evilness` -> `$this->evilness`)

Comment: So if I want to call a function within a class after I defined the instance, I just need to have a class without a destructor?

Comment: The provided example is actualy bad. A `destructor` could be used to save the properties of the current instance to a database/file/... when there are no longer any instances towards it. If you want to call an method after creating a class you just need to do : `$foo = new Boss(); $foo->changeEvilness(42);`. Note: a class/function should **never** be responsonable for outputting output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code below and it works? You have to change `$this->$evilness` to `$this->evilness` in the changeEvilness function

```
<?php

    class Baddie {
        public $evilness = 10;
    }

    class Boss extends Baddie {
        public $evilness = 50;

        public function changeEvilness($value)
        {
            $this->evilness = $value;
        } 

        public function __destruct() {

            echo "You beat the boss!";
        }

    }

    $ganon = new Boss;
    echo $ganon->evilness ."\n";
    $ganon->changeEvilness(1337);
    echo $ganon->evilness ."\n";
?>
```

this outputs:

```
50
1337
You beat the boss!
```

So as you can see, the `constructor`, `changeEvilness()` function and the `destructor` all get called.

Also it's good to know that the php process ends when the last line of code is reached. So because you have nothing after the `$ganon = new Boss`, it will stop the php process and call the destructor.

Comment: I meant the `changeEvilness` function. Sorry, I changed it!

Comment: The `destructor` will also be called if there are no more references of it before the process is ended (I know, it's a detail)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part, I got it the way you have it. I think I was confused that when I don't call the function to change the value it calls the destructor right away, which makes sense, but in the examples he still uses unset() - that part I don't get.

Comment: You can use `unset` when you don't longer need the instance. It's similar to `$foo = null;`. This is done to clear some resources (memory) in the script, boosting it's performance